# py.test hangs after showing test results

Tags: pytest

I'm using py.test to run a bunch of tests. The tests seem to pass, but the process never terminates:

> ===== test session starts =====
>
> platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.4
>
> collected 179 items
>
> common/tests/test_bar.py ...............
>
> common/tests/test_foo.py .......
>
> ....
>
> ===== 159 passed, 20 skipped in 98.58 seconds =====
>
> <-- the prompt never gets back -->

Any ideas what can cause this and how to debug?

**EDIT**

@hpk42 is right - it was a non-daemon thread that never terminated.

Comment: Are you starting threads or server loops within your tests and don't terminate them?

Comment: @hpk42 - write this as an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's likely that your tests start a thread with server loops.  If that is the case, you may use `thread.setDaemon(True)` which marks the thread as "can be thrown away" and might help to get through the Python shutdown. Ideally, though, you should rather signal to your thread/loop that it should terminate.